# Calculating the maximum time difference from a list in python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, datetime

I am trying to solve a problem wherein i have been provided with a list of strings representing times, these time values are nothing but the time at which an alarm clock goes off at different times of a day. I need to find out the maximum time for which the alarm does not snooze. And also the alarm snoozes for a minute before going off.

```
Input 1 - ["14:51"]

Output 1 - "23:59". If the alarm goes off now, it will not go off for another 23 hours and 59 minutes.

Input 2 - ["23:00","04:22","18:05","06:24"]

Output 2 - "11:40". The max interval that the alarm will not go off is 11 hours and 40 minutes.

Any lead on how should i proceed?
```

Comment: "the maximum time for which the alarm does not snooze" can you explain a bit better? Do you mean the longest time between alarms?

Comment: Exactly, it means the longest time between alarms.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this, using a conversion to minutes (integer), and back to time format:

```
def minutes(s):
    return int(s[0:2]) * 60 + int(s[-2:])

def timeformat(m):
    return "{:02d}:{:02d}".format(m // 60, m % 60)

alarms = ["23:00","04:22","18:05","06:24"]

m = [minutes(alarm) for alarm in sorted(alarms)]
intervals = [(m[(i+1)%len(m)] - a - 1) % (60*24) for i, a in enumerate(m)]
result = timeformat(max(intervals)) # 11:40
```

In case duplicates are allowed to occur in the input, then first remove those with:

```
alarms = list(set(alarms))
```

#### Explanation of the intervals calculation:

`for i, a in enumerate(m)` will get the minutes from `m`, but also their indexes (in `i`). The value of `i` is used to point to the next value in `m`. This should wrap around, so that the "next" after the last entry is the first one. This wrapping around is achieved with `%len(m)`. This will convert `i+1` to 0 in case it goes beyond the length of the `m` list.

The difference with the current and next value is calculated with `m[(i+1)%len(m)] - a`. One is subtracted from that because the challenge says that one minute counts as snoozing. As this difference could become negative -- again, in the case of wrapping around -- the modulo trick is applied again to make sure the difference is in the range of [0, 24*60), i.e. in a 24 hour range. So we do `% (60*24)`.

This produces a list of intervals, where each interval is in the range [0, 24*60).

Comment: Works well for the second input but for the first input - ["14:51"], returns  "-1:59", which should be "23:59".

Comment: Indeed, that is now corrected: the `- 1` operation should happen one line earlier.

Comment: It helped solve the first input but random test cases are failing now.                          Like - \n                                                                                                          
          '23:59' should equal '00:15'
          '23:59' should equal '00:33'                                                                                      It seems for all the test cases that are failing the time calculated is the same  i.e - '23:59'.

Comment: Could you also help me understand what is happening inside the intervals list comprehension.

Comment: I thought the input was a list? Can you be more clear about the inputs that fail and what the expected output is for them?

Comment: Yeah the input is list only what i have mentioned above are the values that are output from our code and expected values.Cannot give you the exact lists which are being inputted to the code but most of the time whenever the code is failing some test case the output from our code is '23:59' only.

Comment: If there are duplicate values in the input, it is necessary to eliminate those. Did you add that line of code too?

Comment: Works now by adding the last line of code. Initially i didn't add it deliberately because the problem did not mentioned about duplicate values but i guess it was needed.Could you please elaborate what is happening inside the intervals list comprehension.Thanks.

Comment: I have added an explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. sort the list in an ascending order.
2. a double for loop where you find the delta time foreach i,j adjacent pair and append those values to a new list (pay attention to the last element of the list, I would put an if condition to deal with it in a different manner when compared with the first element of the list).
3. extract max of that list.

I would use this steps. Now you have to choose which functions to use foreach step.

This for step 1:

```
import datetime
alarms = ["23:00","04:22","18:05","06:24"]
alt=[datetime.datetime.strptime(elem, '%H:%M') for elem in alarms]
alt=[elem.time() for elem in alt]
alt.sort()
```

I suppose using datetime.timedelta class in the double for loop would be the best option to deal with your problem (step 2), es:

**Edit**

```
intervals=[]
for i in range(len(alt)):
  if (i!=len(alt)-1):
    intervals.append(datetime.timedelta(0,0,0,0,alt[i+1].minute,alt[i+1].hour)-datetime.timedelta(0,0,0,0,alt[i].minute+1,alt[i].hour))
  else:
    intervals.append(datetime.timedelta(1,0,0,0,alt[0].minute,alt[0].hour)-datetime.timedelta(0,0,0,0,alt[i].minute+1,alt[i].hour))
print(max(intervals)) #11:40:00
```

Comment: Didn't got it the output should be "11:40" and not "2:02:00"

Comment: the last line of code was an example of what you should put as an argument (with [0] and [1] substituted by the right indices ) in the double for loop.

Comment: edited. the double for loop was unecessary in the end

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach, which avoids indexing and relies on iterators

```
import itertools as it

als = ["23:00", "04:22", "18:05", "06:24"]
# als = ["14:51"]

mins = sorted(int(h)*60+int(m) for h,m in map(lambda a: a.split(":"), als))  # sort the alarm times
mins2 = it.chain((mins[-1], ), mins) # add the last alarm time in front to enable wrapping of the sequence

res = max(a-b if a>b else a+1440-b for a, b in zip(mins, mins2)) - 1  # scan the pairs of two adjacent times and get the max difference
print(f"{res // 60}:{res % 60}")
```

Note how subtracting the one-minute snooze can be done once at the end only